# eslint indent error "Expected indentation of 2 spaces but found 4.", angular 14

Tags: angular, typescript, eslint, indentation

I'm using `"eslint": "^8.23.0"` in angular 14
Everything was OK when I used `"eslint": "^8.22.0"`, after update to `8.23.0` I'm getting the following error:

[image: eslint indent error]

[image: eslint indent error]

My eslint config:

```json
{
  "root": true,
  "ignorePatterns": [
    "projects/**/*"
  ],
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": [
        "*.ts",
        "*.js",
        "*.tsx"
      ],
      "parserOptions": {
        "project": [
          "tsconfig.json"
        ],
        "createDefaultProgram": true
      },
      "extends": [
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/recommended",
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/template/process-inline-templates"
      ],
      "rules": {
        "@angular-eslint/directive-selector": [
          "error",
          {
            "type": "attribute",
            "prefix": "app",
            "style": "camelCase"
          }
        ],
        "@angular-eslint/component-selector": [
          "error",
          {
            "type": "element",
            "prefix": "app",
            "style": "kebab-case"
          }
        ],
        "indent": [
          "error",
          2,
          {
            "SwitchCase": 1,
            "ArrayExpression": "first"
          }
        ],
        "@angular-eslint/template/eqeqeq": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/naming-convention": "error",
        "quotes": "error",
        "semi": "error",
        "no-multiple-empty-lines": "error",
        "comma-dangle": "error"
      }
    },
    {
      "files": [
        "*.html",
        "*.css"
      ],
      "extends": [
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/template/recommended"
      ],
      "rules": {
        "@angular-eslint/template/eqeqeq": "off",
        "@angular-eslint/template/accessibility-elements-content": "error",
        "no-multiple-empty-lines": "error"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

as you can see this is `indent` config:

```json
"indent": [
 "error",
 2,
 {
  "SwitchCase": 1  
 }
]
```

I tested the following config

```json
"indent": [
 "error",
 2,
 {
   "SwitchCase": 1,
   "ArrayExpression": "first"
 }
]
```

I also change `eslint` config to the following:

```json
"indent": "off",
"@typescript-eslint/indent": [
  "error",
  2,
  {
    "SwitchCase": 1
  }
],
```

but nothing changed!

Comment: I'm guessing eslint wants you to use `declarations: [VisitorSettingComponent],`?

Comment: It's not just for arrays, I added another picture to clear question

Comment: The parser eslint is using possibly doesn't understand decorators.

Comment: I'd recommend disabling the `indent` rule. It doesn't seem to understand typescript well enough. At least not in my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After update the following package, the problem gone!

```
@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin  5.36.0  →  5.36.1
@typescript-eslint/parser         5.36.0  →  5.36.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved with these dependencies (in angular 16 project) :

```
...
"@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.8.0",
"@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin-tslint": "^6.8.0",
"@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.8.0",
"eslint": "^8.52.0",
"eslint-plugin-import": "^2.29.0",
"eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "^46.8.2",
"eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "^1.2.3",
...
```